# "SQLite error (10): disk I/O error" when playing Galactic ros2 bag

Tags: sqlite, wrapper, ros2, rosbag

I am currently trying to run a ROS2 (Galactic)-YOLOv5 wrapper on a ROS2 bag recorded on Galactic. I know the wrapper works when it's subscribing to my webcam, however I want it to subscribe to a bag I recorded. My process to play the bag seems pretty standard... I open a terminal, source my Galactic environment, colcon build, source install, and try to run my bag:

```
$ source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash
$ colcon build
$ source install/setup.bash
$ ros2 bag play boson_black/
```

but when I hit enter I get this error:

```
[ERROR] [1658428463.099175201] [rosbag2_storage]: Could not open 'black_boson/' with 'sqlite3'. Error: Failed to setup storage. Error: Could not read-only open database. SQLite error (10): disk I/O error
[ERROR] [1658428463.099218921] [rosbag2_storage]: Could not load/open plugin with storage id 'sqlite3'.
No storage could be initialized. Abort
```

On the ROS2 bag github someone had a similar issue which was due to not having the `rosbag2 sqlite3 storage plugin` installed which is provided by the package `rosbag2_storage_default_plugins`. Assuming this is the issue I:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-rosbag2-storage-default-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-galactic-rosbag2-storage-default-plugins is already the newest version (0.9.1-3focal.20220430.142028).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

which leads me to believe that this is not the problem for me... testing my hypothesis I try to run my bag again and get the same error as before.

I have no idea why this isn't working but if anyone has run into a similar problem or has any ideas on what might be going wrong I'd really appreciate it!